# DotNetOpenAuth MVC 3 Service Provider Example

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I am looking at the OAuthServiceProvider WebForms example that comes with the DotNetOpenAuth project, but would like to implement this into an MVC 3 application instead.

Is there any examples where someone has done this already? I can imagine this is a common scenario that someone has already solved. Google/SO is failing to return any working examples.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This project template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef/) is an ASP.NET MVC web site that includes an OAuth Service Provider authentication module in it.  It also accepts OpenID logins, but you can rip that out if you don't want it.  Granted, the project template looks like it throws in a *lot* of code.  It is much more complete and production ready than a very simple sample that perhaps you can find elsewhere.

Although this project template targets MVC 2, I imagine you might be able to tie it over to MVC 3 fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks for the template. This gives me a good start in the right direction! Thank for the wonderful OAuth tools you have written!

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the tool. Do you know of a simple OAuth consumer stub that I can use to poke this web app? I still can't really see the OAuth in action.

Comment: Yes, DotNetOpenAuth comes with an OAuthConsumerWpf sample app that lets you play the part of an OAuth consumer for an arbitrary OAuth service provider.

Comment: Any chance this could be updated for VS2012? It won't open for me.